# Multiple-entry Schengen type C with “Transito” remark

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, transit-visas, tourist-visas

I am a seafarer and I want to go for a holiday in Europe. Can I use a 2-year multiple-entry type C Schengen visa with “transito” remarks for tourism? Or do I have to apply for a tourist Schengen visa?

(2 years multiple entry with 90 days duration of stay)

Comment: What does the visa say in terms of the duration of stay?

Comment: How long a holiday, and where from/to? My working assumption would be that this visa allows you to spend a few days in the Schengen area for the purpose of *transit to a non-Schengen destination*.

Comment: @Traveller but the Schengen Visa Code was amended years ago to remove visas limited to transit.  Any Schengen short-stay visa can in theory be used for any allowable short stay.  The annotations are supposed to explain the motivation for issuing the visa, not to serve as restrictions on its use.  Angeli: Which country issued the visa, and is it valid for "Schengen states" or does it show a specific list of countries?

Comment: Hello @phoog. It’s issued by Spain & it’s valid for all schengen states. 2 yrs with 90days duration. It’s just got a “transito” remark that’s why I’m doubtful :(

Comment: @Leaderboard it’s 2yrs with 90days duration

Comment: When it was issued? Seafarer are a special category, and during COVID there were special rules to allow crew changes (relaxation of many Schengen's rules). In any case, I would ask the authority which issued the visa (possibly, as @phoog wrote, rules changes). A mail from them gives you more power in case of problems (also because you may need the visa for the job (and again: for Seafarer you can get longer visa with less requirements, if you had a good history).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Issued Sept 2022 valid until Sept 2024.

Comment: @phoog I’ve used it for work to enter Italy already & my schengen exit was only after a month. It was over 5days.

Comment: @phoog does it mean I can use this for tourism?

Comment: @Angeli I have a the same question for a trip we have planned to Italy in Jan , and wanted to find out if you had any issues with your trip ? We have the exact same visa. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

In comments, you wrote

> It’s issued by Spain & it’s valid for all schengen states. 2 yrs with 90days duration. It’s just got a “transito” remark that’s why I’m doubtful

And

> does it mean I can use this for tourism?

My response, initially intended as a comment:

It's very clear on the legal side that under the Schengen codes you should be able to use that visa for tourism.  What isn't clear is the practical side: whether a border officer might interpret "transito" as a restriction rather than an informative annotation and therefore deny entry.

Then I thought to check the [Practical Handbook for Border Guards](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/pages/document/commission-recommendation_en), which says (emphasis added)

> 8.2. A Schengen State should not refuse entry and let the third-country national enter into its
> territory in the following cases:
> (a) on humanitarian grounds, on grounds of national interest or because of
> international obligations;
> (b) if a person not in possession of a visa fulfils the criteria for being issued a visa
> at the border (point 9 of this Section);
> (c) solely because the person holds a multiple entry visa issued by another
> Member State;
> (d) **solely because the person holds a multiple entry visa but travels for a purpose
> other than that might be indicated in the ‘comments’ section of the visa sticker.
> The national comments used by some Member States may be linked to the
> (main) purpose for which the visa was applied for. Such an entry on the visa
> sticker does not prevent the holder from using a valid multiple entry visa to
> travel for other purposes (see also point 8.6 of this Section);**
> (e) [not relevant in your circumstances]

So even on the practical side, you should be fine.  You might consider bringing a copy of the relevant page of the handbook to cover the (very small) possibility that the border guard deviates from it.

To be thoroughly prepared, bring the documents you would use for a fresh visa application so you can show them at the border if asked -- but don't offer them unless asked.

If you can get a written statement from the appropriate consulate that your existing visa is sufficient for your trip, that may be helpful, but you probably won't need it, so don't worry if it isn't possible.  The "appropriate consulate" is the consulate that would issue a new visa for this trip if you needed a new visa.  This means that it would be the consulate representing the country that is the main destination of your tourist trip.  For example, if you're going to France, Germany, and Italy, all for tourism, it would be the one in which you're spending the most time.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful. I will now book my flight to Barcelona & have all my papers ready too just in case they ask. Whew! How stressful it has been. Again, thank you so much.